# Set ipywidget options with nothing selected

Tags: python, callback, jupyter-notebook, traits, ipywidgets

When I want to set options in an `ipywidget` with nothing selected I would simply do this:

```
import ipywidgets as w
w.Select(options=[1, 2], value=None)
```

[image: ipywidget Select]

What if I wanted to set new items (with nothing selected) on an existing object? I would have to:

```
import ipywidgets as w
s = w.Select()
...
s.options = [1,2]
s.value = None
```

But if there is a callback registered to receive notifications on value changes, it would be called twice: with autoselected `1` and then with `None`. `None` can be caught easily, but `1` seems like a valid value chosen by the user. That would be a false callback, since user never really chose it.

Is there an easy way around it?

Comment: I just tried this, if no value is selected, and you set `s.options = [1,2]` then there is still no option selected. Can you just observe a simple function that prints the argument, and add what you see to your question? EDIT: I see now, it DOES select 1, you need to change the options and value in one single go.

Comment: @ac24 and how can I do this in one statement..?

Comment: I just tried using the `with widg.hold_trait_notifications():` context manager but getting some odd behaviour, think there might be a bug here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `s.options = [None, 1, 2]` is good enough. Adding `None` in front avoids firing any unwanted callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer works, but downside is that it's required to have `None` in options.
However, there is one workaround to have only "useful" options in the list, with nothing selected after setting them:

```
import ipywidgets as w
s = w.Select()
...
s.unobserve(select_handler, names='value')
s.options = [1, 2]
s.value = None
s.observe(select_handler, names='value')
```

More details on this can be found in `ipywidgets` [issue #2230](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2230).